# JavaScript Unexpected end of input

Tags: javascript, input

The following code gives me "Unexpected end of input" clues?

```
$('#form1').submit(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $.ajax({  
     type: "POST",  
     url: "form.php",  
     data: $(this).serialize(),  
     success: function() {  
       $('#terminal').load('terminal.php');
     }  
   });
```

Comment: You are missing a `});` to close your call to `submit()`.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the problem is a syntax error.

Answer (score 4):

You just need to add `});` at the end. You have mismatch in opening and closing brackets in your code.

```
$('#form1').submit(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $.ajax({  
     type: "POST",  
     url: "form.php",  
     data: $(this).serialize(),  
     success: function() {  
       $('#terminal').load('terminal.php');
     }  
   })
});
```